# Apache Spark: pass Column as Transformer parameter

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

I defined a pipeline Transformer like this:

```
class MyTransformer(condition: Column) extends SparkTransformer { 
   override def transform(dataset: Dataset[_]): DataFrame = {...}
 }
```

which is then used in a pipeline:

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
pipeline.setStages(Array(new MyTransformer(col("test).equals(lit("value"))))
pipeline.fit(df).transform(mydf)
```

In my transformer, I want to apply a transformation only on rows that verify the condition.

It results in a serialization issue:

```
Serialization stack:
- object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.sql.Column, value: (test = value))
- field (class: my.project.MyTransformer, name: condition, type: class org.apache.spark.sql.Column)
- ...
```

In my understanding, the Transformer are serialized to be dispatched to executors, so every parameter should be serializable.

How can I bypass it? Is there a workaround?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems a bit old...
I don't know if my (untested) idea match your needs.

A solution could be to use the SQL expression (a String instance)

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline()
pipeline.setStages(Array(new MyTransformer("test = 'value'")))
pipeline.fit(df).transform(mydf)
```

and to use `functions.expr()` to convert the expression String to Column instance in `Transformer.transform` method.

This way, the condition is Serializable and the non-serializable objects are created when needed in executors.